# REGEX: Separe intervals between commas

Tags: php, regex, postgresql

**may be [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454414/how-can-i-find-a-string-after-a-specific-string-character-using-regex)**

*I am using PHP and postgres.*

How can I separate words in the form below? The maximun amount of words is 7.

```
word_1, word_2, word_3, ...
```

Comment: Dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470505/regular-expression-for-parsing-csv-in-php

Comment: @Mark: The situation is different, since I need to first convert the data to `"word_1", "word_2", "word_3",...` from `word_1, word_2, word_3` such that whitespaces are removed between the words. before conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with this. Just use PHP implode and explode functions and assembly/reformat the string to whatever you need.

Check this out:
http://matthom.com/archive/2005/06/22/code-mnemonics-php-implode-explode

Answer (score 4):

You can call explode.

```
$string = 'word_1, word_2, ...';
$splitarr = explode(',' $string);
```

Then you can grab the values from the arr like so: $splitarr[0] ... $splitarr[6].

Split in this case is slightly slower than explode, as split takes a regular expression.
http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2007/06/11/php-explode-vs-split/

Answer (score 1):

if words cannot contain any white space you can use the preg_split function:

```
$string="word_1, word_2, word_3"; 
$array=preg_split("/\s*,\s/",$string, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

if you use the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY constant you won't get empty results

Comment: Could you, please, give an example of how to use your code. I run unsuccessfully `echo array[0]`, since it prints all words separated by a comma. I would like to print only the word `word_1`.