# How to refine this parsing-csv regexp in php to parse comma in string value?

Tags: php, regex, csv

I am using the answer of joker83 in this question: [Regular expression for parsing CSV in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470505/regular-expression-for-parsing-csv-in-php) but I find it can't parse csv string whose field value containing comma correctly. Is it possible to refine this regexp to solve this problem?

**Explanation of the pattern from joker83: `/,(?=(?:[^\"])*(?![^\"]))/`**.
1. `,(?=x)` means a comma that follows a pattern x.
2. `[^\"]` means some character other than double quote.
3.`(?:[^\"])` means match the parenthesis-ed subpattern but don't capture it into matched resulting array.
4. `*` means 0 or more of the specified pattern.
5.`(x)*` means 0 or more of the pattern x.
6. `y?![^\"]` means a **y** that NOT follows some character not double quote(i.e. matching y that follows a dobule quote)
7. The whole meaning is matching a comma that follows a double quote (where * means zero ) or matching a comma that follows 1 or more of characters other than double quote and these characters follows a double quote.

As you can see, if the csv string is ***120,"I love ""Lexi Belle"", ""Proxy Paige""","good stuff"***, then when apply this regexp in preg_split, we will get 4 fields (i.e. **`120`** **`"""I Love Lexi Bell""`** **`""Proxy Piage"""`** **`"good stuff"**`)rather than the correct 3 fields.

**Note:** I'm using PHP5.2.6 (can't upgrade to new version since I spent a lot of time to install a oci8 that can read Oracle 8i on Windows. I can't install them correctly again in new version of PHP).
**Note:**  I can't use fgetcsv() either since the input csv file contains LF code in csv string and fgetcsv() will split the newline in the middle of that field.

Comment: *"I am using the answer of joker83 in this question"*, you should not.

Comment: As my notes show, his answer is best suitable one for my case then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/
```

Which is found from this stackoverflow entry [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) (but for java).

On your string it gives:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "120"
  [1]=>
  string(31) ""I love Lexi Bell, Proxy Paige""
  [2]=>
  string(12) ""good stuff""
}
```

Note that you still have the '"' on them.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need. I accept this as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.str-getcsv.php)?

```
$string = '120,"I love Lexi Bell, Proxy Paige","good stuff"';
$parsedCsv = str_getcsv($string);
print_r($parsedCsv);
```